# how to sort a list of some model by their TimeOfDay in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

here is my model

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6AbJ.png

here i am trying to break every timeOfDay to a copy of the same entity to form a complete list of times

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWBHZ.png

I'd like to sort the new list by timeOfDay, or find a better way to achieve what i wanted.

thank you in advance and sorry for my messed idea.

```
 class Medication {
  final int dosage;
  final int durationOfUsage;
  final int intervalOfUsage;
  bool isAlertable;
  final int maxUnites;
  final String name;
  DateTime? startDate;
  final int timesPerDay;
  final List<TimeOfDay> toBeTakenAt;
  final String unite;
  final int unitesPerUsage;
}

List<Medication> getMedications(List<Medication> medications) {
  final tempList = <Medication>[];
  for (final medication in medications) {
    for (final element in medication.toBeTakenAt) {
      tempList.add(medication.copyWith(toBeTakenAt: [element]));
    }
  }
  return tempList;
}
```

Comment: [Read and abide by this please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 0):

can you try the below code.

```
List<Medication> getMedications(List<Medication> medications) {
 return medications.sort((a,b) => a.toBeTakenAt.compareTo(b.toBeTakenAt));
}
```